# How to have IntelliJ Idea 16 understand .coalesce() methods in QueryDSL

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullable, querydsl, coalesce

I have the following code in a DAO class:

```
public Integer getSum() {
    return new JPAQuery(entityManager)
        .from(querydslTable)
        .singleResult(querydslTable.intColumn.sum().coalesce(0));
}
```

The query should never return null since it coalesces the result to 0 but intelliJ complains with the following warning:

> Expression 'new JPAQuery(entityManager) .from(querydslTable)
>   .singleResult(querydslT...' might evaluate to null but is returned by
>   the method which is not declared as @Nullable

Does IntelliJ lack support for queryDSL introspection or is it actually warning me that if there are no rows in the table it will in fact return `null`?

Thank you

Comment: It's been a while since I messed around with QueryDSL, but is there a chance that `sum()` could actually return `null`?

Comment: @Makoto there sure is, but then I coalesce to 0.

Comment: It's not like IntelliJ is lying to you, then.  You can't dereference `null`, so if `sum()` *did* return `null`, you would get an NPE.

Comment: It is not warning me about NPE, it is warning me about null return type. And that NPE would have been dealt with by QueryDSL itself, it is normal to have sum() return null but if you append coalesce(0) you don't get NPE, you get 0 I know that for a fact.

Comment: IntelliJ is smarter than that.  I'd trust it before your code.  Maybe this is a good spot for a JDK 8 Optional.

Comment: It is not Optional, whatever the data on the DB this query NEVER returns null.